# Create Materialized View from foreign table

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view, postgresql-9.5, foreign-data

I'd like to create a simple *materialized view* from a table which lies in a different database. The two databases are on the same server.

What do I have to add to make the query access the foreign database and the table there?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_table_1 AS
  SELECT *
  FROM public.mv_table_1 --The schema & table from the different DB
WITH DATA;
```

I tried using the fully qualified table name (db name before the schema name) but this results in an error:

> References to other dbs are not implemented

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PostgreSQL databases cannot "see" each other by default. This is a good thing.

You can make one pg database see another by using the postgres_fdw Foreign Data Wrapper: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html

Steps:

1. Add the extension
2. Create the foreign server
3. Create the user mapping
4. Create the foreign table. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-importforeignschema.html if you have 9.5+
5. Create the materialized view pointing to the foreign table

Comment: THank's for the explanation. However when executing the IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA command I always get a syntax error although I'm pretty sure that my syntax's alright:    

`IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public
  LIMIT TO (table_1) 
  FROM SERVER foreign_server 
  INTO public;`    Table_1 is in the public schema of DB2 and I want it to be read into the public schema of DB1. Any idea?

Comment: OK, it works now. A good tutorial:
http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/foreign-data-wrappers-for-postgresql